# Can a male rabbi teach Torah lessons to a woman?

Tags: halacha, women, torah-study, pirke-avot-ethicsof

1. Assuming all laws of *yichud* are complied with, are there additional concerns arising from a male rabbi teaching Torah classes to a female student?
2. Does the answer to 1 differ if they are both married, one married one not, or both single?
3. How does one apply the *mishneh* in *Pirkei Avos* of not to engage in too much conversation with women to this situation?

Comment: Torah study is conversation?? The mishna says conversation that isn't Talmud Torah

Comment: I don't think that question #3 is relevant to the other two questions unless you can show some relevance or explain your concern. You may want to ask that as a separate question. Also, please clarify if your concern is specific to an individual lesson or a rabbi teaching a class that has only women attending. (More than one.)

Comment: See this summary of R. Mazuz's view on the matter: http://www.ykr.org.il/modules/Ask/answer/10487. See also Rav Mazuz's own presentation of his position here: http://www.ykr.org.il/modules/Ask/answer/3137 and here: http://www.ykr.org.il/modules/Ask/answer/11985. He is dealing with lectures to multiple women. He says it is alright as long as they are generally modest, and men attending are separate from women (when applicable). He specifies that he should not lecture on _taharat hamishpaha_.

Comment: #3 the gemarah in pesachim (i think) says that Bruriah Rabbi Meir's wife chastised Reb Yosi for saying extra words to her.

Comment: @mevaqesh If lecturing to a group of women would be prohibited, there would be no way that women could sit in shul on Shabbat listening to the rav's *drasha* - unless he talked only about baseball stats.

Comment: @DanF that is correct. he is primarily talking about ladies only lectures. also in the case of a shabbat derasha, it is more a matter of assumption that they will be behind a mehitsa, and interacting less with the speaker, than in most cases of ladies lectures, or even of a mixed-sex lecture.

Comment: @DanF the question is just as it is: *A* male rabbi, teaching *A* woman. If you google around, you'd see there is a lot of debate about the enhanced applicability of the mishnah to married women (if convo between a husband and wife should not be excessive, how much more prohibited is it to have excessive conversation with a single member of the opposite sex). Why does the comment section always become the Yeshiva World Coffee Room?

Comment: @mevaqesh It sounds like items in your comment (from Rav Mazuz) would make a satisfactory answer that's better than the Yeshiva World Coffee Room schmooze. You should consider posting it.

Comment: Maybe a related question here: Given that it is clearly _allowed_, still is there a downside to a man teaching women because he is going to have to deal with his own tznius issues as a result? How big a role should that play in such a decision? Does it depend on the man?

Comment: I'd add that I had to deal with exactly that question recently.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding question 3, I assume you are referring to [Avot 1:5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31565&st=&pgnum=6). The term used in the Mishnah is שיחה which loosely means "conversation" or "chatter". It does not refer to Torah talk. How can it refer to Divrei Torah if the end of the Mishnah says that one who engages in שיחה takes away from *Divrei Torah*? That would be paradoxical!

See Rav Bartenura's explanation to what type of "talk" this refers to. He mentions talking about bad things that occurred to him (a form of lashon hara) at the market or similar.

In short, the Mishnah in Avot doesn't seem relevant to your question.

Answer (score 2):

[DailyHalacha.com](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=703) says that so long as there are two or more ladies in a room that does not lock, or with the door open if there is a lock, or if his wife or mother are in the room a man may teach ladies.

Thus there are no additional concerns besides the Yichud concerns.

Comment: The question already assumed that "all laws of yichud are complied with". This answer just seems to discuss the laws of yichud.

Comment: Who wrote that on that website?